# Question about unions of probabilities of disjoint sets.

Tags: probability

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$ and assume that the various sets mentioned below are all in A. Show that if $D_i$ are disjoint and $P(C|D_i) = p$ independently of $i$, then $P(C|\bigcup_iD_i) = p$.

The question is number 4a in Hoel, Port, and Stones' *Introduction to Stochastic Processes.*  I've been spending a good amount of time on this question and always start by splitting it into $\frac{P(C,D_i)}{P(D_i)}$ using Bayes's theorem, but have no idea how to rewrite it in terms of the union.  I also tried starting with $\frac{P(D,\bigcup_iD_i)}{P(\bigcup_iD_i)}$ and got nowhere.  I figure at some point I have to turn these into summations but don't know where to go from there.

(Also sorry if this should be on CrossValidated.  I was debating which one to post this under.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $D=\bigcup_{i}D_{i}$.

$$P\left(C\mid D\right)P\left(D\right)=P\left(C\cap D\right)=\sum_{i}P\left(C\cap D_{i}\right)=$$$$\sum_{i}P\left(C\mid D_{i}\right)P\left(D_{i}\right)=\sum_{i}pP\left(D_{i}\right)=p\sum_{i}P\left(D_{i}\right)=pP(D)$$

Implying that: $$P(C\mid D)=p$$ if $P(D)>0$